# Terminate While Loop with if statement and break

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, character-encoding, python-3.6

Okay I am now adding a bit of sophistication to my encryption I have created.
I am working on implementing a While loop to generate a amount of characters from a dictionary I have created. Then check as the characters are added to a variable, next terminate the while loop after it reaches the amount of characters needed. And for some reason the while loop never terminates, even when I use return 0 or break and others.

```
Alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l",      "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", '/', '.', ',', '\'', ';', '\\', ']', '[', '{', '}', '|', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '+', '-', '0', '0', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

while True:
    generaterandom = random.SystemRandom.choice() 
    calc0 = len(generaterandom)
    print(generaterandom)
    calc02 = 10
    if generaterandom == "10":
        break
```

Comment: Without getting into your code, (which doesn't run), your check should probably be:
if calc0 == calc02:

Answer (score 0):

```
if generaterandom == "10":
```

This is your issue, you are checking to see if `generaterandom` is a string with the value of `10` what you want to do is have it end when it hits 10 characters, so you need to change your if statement to:

```
if len(generaterandom) == 10:
    break
```

This will change it to check if the amount of characters in the variable `generaterandom` is equal to 10, and when it is equal to 10 your loop will break.

If that does not work restructure your loop so that it works on a variable, for example:

```
loop = True
while loop:
```

To start it and to end it:

```
if len(generaterandom) == 10:
    loop = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to restructure your *While* loop like this:

```
Alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l",      "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", '/', '.', ',', '\'', ';', '\\', ']', '[', '{', '}', '|', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '+', '-', '0', '0', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
bool = 1
while bool == 1:
    generaterandom = random.SystemRandom.choice() 
    calc0 = len(generaterandom)
    print(generaterandom)
    calc02 = 10
    if len(generaterandom) == "10":
        bool = 0
```